# javascript quotation issue. Chrome gives syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I have following line in my javascript:

```
$tasksContainer.append(html + "<label><input type="checkbox" class="js-task" data-index="" + index + "" data-task-selected="false">" + tasks[task].taskName + "</label></div>");
```

Chrome console says: 'TaskView.js:118 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Comment: You will have to escape your quotes within the html string: `"<label><input type=\"checkbox\" ... "`. (Or use single quotes around the html string)

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: You should use a templating engine instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the double quotes around a fixed string to single quotes.

> 'Hello "World"!'

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes inside double quotes:

```
$tasksContainer.append(html + "<label><input type='checkbox' class='js-task' data-index='" + index + "' data-task-selected='false'>" + tasks[task].taskName + "</label></div>");
```